# jmeter distribution load testing for no result return from slave to master gui mode

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

I am not getting any result from slave machine also no entry in DB
1. connectivity between master and slave is established since when i run remote from master, slave states 'Start the test' 'Finish the test'
2. also from single master and slave script is executed successfully
3. also since there is dynamic ip to server so i am not able to provide ip and port

Not able to catch what exactly is the problem, if you can check through Team viewer, please guide me further as you get some time

[slave machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9eAB.png)
[master machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEjdm.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure both master and slave are running the same Java version
2. Make sure both master and slave are running the same JMeter version (also consider upgrading to latest JMeter version - [JMeter 3.3](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) as of now)
3. If you use any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) or there are any libraries in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) make sure to copy them over to slave machines as well.
4. Check **jmeter-server-log** on slave side
5. If you want to see request and response details in GUI add the next line to *user.properties* file for all slaves:

   ```
   mode=Standard
   ```

Check out [How to Load Test Opening a URL on a Remote Machine with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-opening-a-url-on-a-remote-machine-with-jmeter) article for comprehensive explanation and step-by-step instructions.

Comment: since my website in hosted dynamic IP to server through traffic manager so i am not able to provide ip and port, so is it necessary to provide IP and Port?

also how can i check jmeter-server-log on slave side?

Comment: You **have to** provide either hostname or ip address otherwise you'll get something like `URI does not specify a valid host name`. If you omit the port JMeter will use defaults like 80 for http or 443 for https.  `jmeter-server-log` file should appear in JMeter's "bin" folder when you launch `jmeter-server.bar` or `jmeter-server`